# Is there a way to generate list names by using strings from an imported csv?

Tags: python, csv, import

I'm attempting to import a csv file that has a many inputs of text strings followed by several values. Something like:

`FruitBat, 20, 46, 12, 45. RocketTurtle, 45, 22, 17, 90`

I would like to be able to import this csv such that it automatically generates lists named `FruitBat` and `RocketTurtle` such that:

`FruitBat = [20, 46, 12, 45]`, `RocketTurtle=[45, 22, 17, 90]`, etc.

The actual file I wish to import is several hundred inputs. Is there any good way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Have you already written code to read the csv file, or are you making that part of the question?

Comment: I can import a csv file and its data fine, the issue is getting the code to generate list names based on the imported strings.

Comment: Please provide a sample of input data.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/UTF9QmU here's a bit of the csv I'm working with. I would need it to output something like cs137=[ 109999996.147162, 59041804.3408036, 29573360.5568435, 23486287.013845, 
18652113.5004746, 14812956.0806909, 11764010.9708154,
9342629.07198266, 7419639.28741607, 5892457.75800508]

Comment: I updated my answer to work with your example string.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is specific need for the variables to be made seperately, it would be easier to just store these as key-value pairs inside a dictionary.

You could read the files and use the first element as the key and slice the rest of the elements into a list.

```
import csv

# dictionary to hold all the lists
output_dict= {}

with open('file.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        # store key-value pairs
        output_dict[row[0]] = row[1:]

# get the corresponding values
print(output_dict["FruitBat"])
```

If you really want to create seperate variables, might be worth looking at [globals()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals)

Answer (score 0):

You can split the strings by commas, and then make a dictionary with the data:

```py
import re

arr = yourString.split(",")

players = {} #I'm calling them players; I don't really know what they are

currentPlayer = arr[0]

players[currentPlayer] = []

for i in range( len(arr) ):
    if not re.search('[A-Za-z]', arr[i]): #If there are no letters in it
        players[currentPlayer].append(arr[i]) #add it to that player
    else: #If there were letters in it
        currentPlayer = arr[i]
        players[currentPlayer] = []

print(players)
```

I hope this helps!

EDIT:
I didn't realize your 'players' data was separated by periods. In that case, you could do a similar thing like this:

```py
import re

players_arr = yourString.split(".")

players = {}

for i in range( len(players_arr) ):
    data = players_arr[i].split(",")
    player = ""
    for j in range( len(data) ):
        if not re.search('[A-Za-z]', data[j]):
            players[player].append(data[j])
        else:
            player = data[j].strip()
            players[player] = []

print(players)
```